# Endless processing and stuck with replace and left

Tags: excel, vba

This is about VBA in excel.

I am trying to remove the sign "/" and cut the string length for every cell down to 31 to make those values valid as a name for a new sheet. The constraint is within the first two columns until the last occupied row.

My code compiled, however, it brought me endless processing and I have to task manager-exit every time after running it. Please take a look at it, thank you so much!

```
Sub replaceSpeCharaAndCutLength()

'selectPositionAndReplaceSpeCharaAndCutLength Macro

Dim cell As Range
Dim row As Long

    For row = 7 To Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Replace _
        What:="/", Replacement:="_", _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
        
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("B").Replace _
        What:="/", Replacement:="_", _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
    
        For Each cell In Sheet1.Range("A:B").Cells
        cell.Value = Left(cell.Value, 31)
        Next cell
    Next row
End Sub
```

Updated code 0142 08212020

```
Sub replaceSpeCharaAndCutLength()
'
' selectPositionAndReplaceSpeCharaAndCutLength Macro
'
Dim cell As Range

    
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Replace _
        What:="/", Replacement:="_", _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
        
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("B").Replace _
        What:="/", Replacement:="_", _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
    
    For Each cell In Sheet1.Range("A:B").Cells
        cell.Value = Left(cell.Value, 31)
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Move the inner `For Each` outside so its a separate loop and only loop to the last row? You don't need the first `For` loop either. You don't need a loop to `replace`.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you, and I have removed the ```for``` loop, and made the ```for each``` looping within range("A:B") but apparently it still runs endless. I will edit my question to upload the new code, thanks!

Comment: `For Each cell In Sheet1.Range("A:B").Cells` covers **EVERY** cell in the range, so your loop isn't endless, just very long!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range.Replace` doesn't require a loop. You can also use `Evaluate` instead of the other loop:

```vb
Sub replaceSpeCharaAndCutLength()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A7:B" & lastRow)

    rng.Replace _
        What:="/", Replacement:="_", _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True

    rng.Value = rng.Parent.Evaluate("INDEX(LEFT(" & rng.Address & ",31),)")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I noticed the entire B column was also replaced with the content in A, is it possible to do the same replaceSpeChara and cut length for B column's original content? Thanks!

Comment: Try the revised last line (I forgot that the original version I posted works only in versions of Excel that support dynamic array formulas).